# How to load ~/.Xresources when starting X?

Tags: linux, xorg, arch-linux

I've edited my ~/.Xresources and issued xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources and it worked perfectly. However when I restart X, the settings are changed to default. I've also added xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources in ~/.xinitrc but that did not worked. Please give a solution.
I'm using Arch Linus with awesome wm.

Answer (score 7):

If you aren't using a display manager to login, you need to add the following to your `~/.xinitrc` file.

```
[[ -f ~/.Xresources ]] && xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

Most display managers will load `~/.Xresources` automatically.

Comment: i've added this line but it didn't worked! i've added exec awesome to xinitrc and it works so i can say xinitrc it being loaded

Comment: thanks for your solution. i just added the line before executing awesome and it worked

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad you got it working! :)